# How can i use TextToSpeech functionality without having any interface ?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

How can i use TextToSpeech functionality without having any interface ? I am developing a app for visually Impaired persons , i just need to generate a voice alert, and the text (alert will be hard coded). Can anyone help me with this ? I am getting error on this  TextToSpeech.OnInitListener ..... Is interface is necessory for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private TextToSpeech tts;

    public static void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_your);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(YourActivity.this, InitListener);
    }

    private TextToSpeech.OnInitListener InitListener = new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                int res = tts.setLanguage("en", "US", "");
                if (res >= TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
                    String text = "Input text what you want to say.";
                    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This app doesn't need UI, and will make voice just once when app is executed.